# Switch the Zend Framework Version on Zend Server CE

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-server-ce

So, I have recently installed the new Zend Server CE 6.0.0.

Now, if I go to `localhost:10081/ZendServer/ServerInfo/` I get the following info on top:

- PHP Version 5.4.11
- Zend Server Version: 6.0.0
- Zend Framework:1.12.1, 2.1.1**
- Zend Server Gateway: 0.9.0.201301302347
- Build: 68518

As you can see, there are two Zend Framework versions installed, 1.12.1 and 2.1.1.

If I use `echo Zend_Version::VERSION;` in my application it shows me `1.12.1`.

**Question:** How do I switch these different versions? And how am I able to add even more versions (e.g. additionally 1.12.3)?

Comment: if you are using multiple versions I would recommend you use local installations, using Composer. You won't get any conflics between framework versions and won't have issues whyen you need to upgrade the framework either.

Comment: Ok, thanks Andrew for the advice with Composer. Will have a look at it!

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I switch these different versions?

if you are using non namespaced code you are using Zend Framework 1:

```
echo Zend_Version::VERSION;//this is ZF1 style code
```

if the code is namespaced it's Zend Framework 2:

```
echo Zend\Version::VERSION;//this would be ZF2 style code
```

you're not likely to use the wrong one by accident.

With Zend Server both versions of Zend Framework are located in the `/ZendServer/share` directory (windows) and included in the `php.ini include_path`. If you don't want one or the other available edit it out of you `php.ini include_path`.

**NOTE:** often the `include_path` entry in the `php.ini` for Zend Server is located at the end of the document instead of in the usual location.

```
 And how am I able to add even more versions (e.g. additionally 1.12.3)?
```

This is the easy part;

Add the new version to the `Zendserver/share` directory and then add the new path to the `php.ini include_path`.

```
include_path=".;C:\Zend\ZendServer\bin\pear;C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library;C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework2\library"
```

Path

```
    /Zend
        /ZendServer
            /share
                /Zendframework
                /Zendframework2
```

Good Luck